# Can't delete a jar file on windows? Scala/Spark/IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jar

I generated a .jar file from my Scala project in IntelliJ, I accidently added some stuff that it doesnt need. But now I cant create a new .jar file because it doesnt have permission to overwrite it, and I cant even remove the .jar file manually?

Im on Windows 10.

If I try to remove it on the command line with rm -r it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Note that `rm` is not a standard Windows command.

Comment: I tried rm in Ubuntu for Windows but also del and deleting manually

Comment: Try restarting Windows.

Comment: If you really attempted to delete the file with the correct commands, what was the result of that action? What was the error message? Is the file locked, do you have the correct access rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe jar file in use, try to clear cache and rebuild your app in inteljIDE.

Comment: If I try to rebuild in IntelliJ it also says file cannot be removed

Comment: File -> Project Structure. Check tab problems, you can fix it easy with suggest. Then go tab Libraries and click (-) to remove jar file. If you can capture your problem, post here to more info to fix.